# Mudar a cor da linha do DataGridView

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como faço para mudar a cor de uma linha toda do `DataGridView`. Tenho um código abaixo, porém ele só mudar a cor de uma coluna específica, e eu gostaria que ele mudasse a cor de todas as colunas da mesma linha.

```
DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `dataGridView1.CurrentRow`.[`DefaultCellStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) e deixe o `dataGridView1`.[`SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) que é a seleção completa da linha:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new object[]
{
    new {Id = 1, Nome = "A"},
    new {Id = 2, Nome = "B"},
}
.ToList();

// configuração que marca a linha completa.
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataGridView1.Update();
dataGridView1.Select();
// configuração do estilo da linha
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

***Referencias:***

- [DataGridView.SelectionMode Propriedade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle Propriedade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)